# Table row reference and value transfer

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table that is set up like this

```
            <tbody>
                <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="display:none"><?php echo $row['Knygos_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Pavadinimas']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Leidimo_metai']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Puslapiu_skaicius']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Kaina_eurais']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <p class = "btn editbtn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
                        <p class = "btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile ?>
            </tbody>
```

Query is simple `SELECT * FROM knyga`. What i need to do is when i click on a button to reference it to another page `knyga_form` with `Knygos_id` value of the clicked row so that the page could populate itself with data from sql query.

Do i need to do the reference part with javascript `onclick()` or is there a different method with php maybe that i dont know? href maybe?

Also, how do I transfer the needed `Knygos_id` to different page?

the url for now would go like this `http://localhost:81/servisai/knygynas/knyga_form.php`

Comment: Are you familiar with ajax?

Comment: i dont think so, but willing to get acquainted

Comment: javascript onclick() will handle this case effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can redirect to `knyga_form` using  `anchor<a>` tag.

```
<a href='http://localhost:81/servisai/knygynas/knyga_form.php?Knygos_id=<?php echo $row['Knygos_id']; ?>' class = "btn editbtn">
      <span class = "fa fa-edit">
      </span>
   </a>
```

In `Knyga_form`  you can get the `Knygos_id` in $_GET['Knygos_id'], then you can populate form.

Comment: hmm... the button doesnt work though. it just refreshes the current page

Comment: you have to create knyga_form.php to show full details of Knygos_id

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: nevermind. it was my old script file that was doing something else on click  and interfering.

Comment: let me know clearly, on click of <p> tage, you need to populate data for that id which row you click and in same page right ??

Comment: in `knyga_form` page. the current page is `knyga`. I pretty much didnt know how to transfer needed `Knygos_id` from one page to another. but now having this suggestion solved it